# What should I put on my application in regards to termination?

Tags: applications

I was lead case manager at a halfway house.  When I was terminated I was not provided with a clear reason.  An intern had confided in me that the assistant director had grabbed her buttocks while she was walking out of her office.  During that time there was a lot of shady things going on with the residents that if the contract specialist at the BOP would have known about they probably would have either shut the place down or gotten rid of the assistant director.  He was made aware that all of these issues had been brought to my attention and fired me 2 days later.  I realize that I was a liability.  But my question is what should my answer be during my interview or on my applications?

Comment: Your question is full of speculations and assumptions. **Those** should definitely not be in your answer.

Comment: Please [edit] your answer, explain BOP, and add a country tag. This is an international platform.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, this falls under the common but potentially very tricky interview questions. However Jessie, this is not something you would outright declare.  In most countries with contract/employment law (US and UK at least I believe - see references below) there is zero requirement to tell your future employer that you were sacked/fired from your previous role.

So your reply of main focus should really be what you learnt from your past experience and how you plan to put your lessons into practice to be a better professional.  For example:

> “After we lost the huge client account, in no small part due to my error, I spent a lot of time reflecting on the customer experience and how to ensure I keep the customer top-of-mind in everything I do. I believe this will be a tremendous asset in my next role.”

You comments must show the prospective employer how what you have learned makes you a better fit for the role you are applying for.

Some further resources:

- http://idealistcareers.org/how-to-tell-a-potential-employer-you-were-fired/
- http://www.bloomberg.com/bw/management/how-not-to-say-i-was-fired-08302011.html

Answer (score 1):

As long as none of what has happened is public knowledge, I'd be cautious about going beyond generically vague "internal politics" or "didn't get along with my boss" type reasons.  Even if you were to win in the end a bogus libel/slander lawsuit would be very expensive and seriously hinder your ability to find/maintain new employment while it's going on.  (By consuming a large amount of your time, if nothing else.)

If the major problems there become public knowledge, via someone else's actions, you can be more open; but still need to avoid saying anything that sounds could be misinterpreted as you're trying to scapegoat them for something else that would have given them a justifiable reason to fire you.

Comment: Telling a prospective employer you successfully sued the last one who fired you generally doesn't improve your chances anyway.

Comment: @Namfuak My concerns about litigation were entirely from the other direction.  The crooked employer suing their ex-employer to try and force them to stop talking about the organizations faults.